# What's with this question? Migration rejected?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, meta

Sorry, just curious. [This meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345958/1016716) says

> migration rejected from [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43009795/revisions)

below it, but it obviously was migrated, since it's now here.
Also I can't comment to it.
So what happened there? I'm curious!

Comment: It it still on main site http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009795/the-hidden-power-of-stack-overflow-how-a-website-you-ve-never-heard-of-is-holdi for some reason.

Comment: It did get migrated, but it got closed (and not as a duplicate) on the target site (eg: here) - so the migration is rejected and the post gets a noticed and locked to prevent further input on the post.

Comment: @JonClements Wait, you mean the message "Migration rejected" is a (confusing) way of saying the question was locked after migration? If so, that wasn't very clear then.

Comment: @MrLister The lock is a consequence of the migration rejection, which was caused by the Q getting closed on the target site.